# Create a dictionary to show number of employees from specific States

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a linq Object say "Employees".

I am trying to grab the state of residence for each Employee in the list of employees and create a dictionary (key, value). Where Key being a state that exists in the list and the value being the number of time it occurs in the list.

So far:-

```
 foreach(var elem in Employees)
            {
                var stateDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                stateDictionary["State"] = elem.State;

                Console.Write(stateDictionary["State"]);
            }
```

This will only store the name of the State for the last time each elem is read from Employees.

How can I proceed to address my goal?

The end result should allow me to say :-

MN - 5
CA - 2
OR - 33
WA - 21

etc... Each state and the number of employees from that state.

Comment: Didn't you mean to put the declaration of stateDictionary outside your foreach? Now your creating a new Dictionary per element and throw it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use LINQ. The following statement will create a dictionary with state as key, and count of employees per state as value:

```
Employees.GroupBy(e => e.State).ToDictionary(g => g.Key.State, g => g.Count());
```

If you want to keep imperative approach, this will work:

```
var stateDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var e in Employees)
{
    if (!stateDictionary.ContainsKey(e.State)) stateDictionary.Add(e.State, 1);
    else stateDictionary[e.State]++;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what this does and how it works. If he's having trouble understanding simple `foreach` loops he'll have a lot of trouble understanding this.

Comment: I understand lambda calculus. I am also not having issues with Foreach.. I have never used a dictionary before...

Comment: @DaveZych I was just editing the answer to add a working `foreach`. I added an explanation of `ToDictionary` too.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations.

Comment: @JakubLortz  Although I am having an issue with g => g.Key.State ... Its complaining about not having a definition for State. Although it recognizes the EmployeeView class correctly.

Comment: @Philo You should see the properties you used in `GroupBy`

Comment: Well my employee class does have the state propoerty.     
public class EmployeeView
    {
        public DateTime DateOfHire { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @Philo The answer is close.  You don't need `g.Key.State`, it is just `g.Key`